# Getting Values from 2 different Textboxes and finding the Average of it in the Third Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
protected void TextBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox4.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox5.Text))
            {
                TextBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text) +            Convert.ToInt32(TextBox4.Text) / 2).To String();
            }

        }
```

TextBox6 Is Not giving me any Answer,  AutopostBack is set to "True".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your 2nd isnull test without a ! (not) missing.

However, text boxes never return null, so this would be better:

First, the markup:

```
Text4:
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="true"
    OnTextChanged="TextBox4_TextChanged">
</asp:TextBox>
<br />
Text5:
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"
    AutoPostBack="true"
    OnTextChanged="TextBox4_TextChanged"
    ></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<h3>Result box</h3>
Text6:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
```

And code behind:

```
protected void TextBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // both text4 and text 5 have ontextchange = this event
    if (TextBox4.Text != "" & TextBox5.Text !="")
    {
        TextBox6.Text = 
            (
            (
            Convert.ToDouble(TextBox4.Text) + 
            Convert.ToDouble(TextBox5.Text)
            ) / 2
            ).ToString();
    }
}
```

result:

[image]

## Edit: Some other code set the 2 values in the text box

Ok, so then say (for example) some code (say a button) sets the 2 values, then we would have this code:

First, our markup:

```
    Text4:
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" >
    </asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    Text5:
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server">

    </asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <h3>Result box</h3>
    Text6:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
<br />

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
    Text="set the 2 text boxes" 
    OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

so, I just dropped in a button, but "some how" and "some palce" those 2 textboxes will get a value set.

however, when you set a textbox (with code), then that those text box events don't THEN fire for you. Those control events ONLY fire when the user changes them, NOT code behind.

So, if a bunch of code is going to update (or fill or set) some values on a page, and you need some calulations to occur?

Then build a "calulator" routine for the page that does all the math etc. for all the controls.

Thus our code becomes this:

```
    void CalulatorCode()
    {
        TextBox6.Text =
            (
            (
            Convert.ToDouble(TextBox4.Text) +
            Convert.ToDouble(TextBox5.Text)
            ) / 2
            ).ToString();

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox4.Text = "123";
        TextBox5.Text = "456";
        CalulatorCode();

    }
```

So, if the controls are to have some values, then yes, YOU the developer will have to write/have/use code to call the calculation routines. just setting the values from code will not trigger any event code attached to each control.

Comment: Lets say we already have values in Textbox4 and Textbox5, we are not inputting ourselves, and need the average of both the values in Textbox6 ,

Comment: Your code is working Perfectly fine when I am inputting anything, But can you please tell me how to do when we already have values in textboxes.

Comment: Ok, but those text boxes did not by magic fill themselves out. How and when and where did you set those values. In other words, how did the values "come to be" in those text boxes? So, perhaps some code did? Then AT THAT point in time, you would also then run the code to set texbox6. So, in software "the context" of the task here is everything. Those 2 text boxes did not by magic get filled out. However, since (we assume) that some code or process set those values, then of course post-back will not trigger nor be required here.

Comment: see my code edit - I show how one would approach some code behind that sets up the 2 textboxes, and then calls some code. So there is no such thing that the text boxes "already" had some value. If code is to setup those 2 textboxes, then that code also responsible for doing the calculations at THAT point in time for code that sets those values.

Comment: So nice of you :)

Answer (score 1):

Division operations have a higher priority than sum operations.
I would recommend to add an extra parenthesis:

```cs
( this>(Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(TextBox4.Text) )<this / 2)
```

Anyhow, your method will update `TextBox6`, whenever `TextBox6` changes.
This will not work.

I recommend having a different method (e.g: private void `DoSum()`) and call this from both `TextBox4_TextChanged` and `TextBox5_TextChanged`.

Comment: I'm also trying to code this same code behind Textbox4 and Textbox5 but still its not working,                                                                                                                                                                      public void TextBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox4.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox5.Text))
            {
                TextBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(TextBox4.Text) / 2).ToString();
            }
        }

Comment: I also tried your technique,                 public void Avg()
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox4.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox5.Text))
            {

                TextBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(TextBox4.Text) / 2).ToString();
            }

        }

        public void TextBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Avg();
        }

        public void TextBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Avg();
        }

Comment: You are still missing the parenthesis for the /2